# Mount folder on MacOS

Tags: macos, mount, hardlink

I want to mount a folder (specifically mount not soft link) in macOS Catalina.

I tried:

`mount -t ufs <path to src folder> <path to dst where I want my mount point>`

I got in return:

`mount: exec ....../mount_ufc for <path to dst where I want my mount point>: No such file or directory`

So I created the folder

`mkdir <path to dst where I want my mount point>`

run again the command and still got
`mount: exec ....../mount_ufc for <path to dst where I want my mount point>: No such file or directory`

How can I mount / hard link folder in macOS?

Comment: You don't mount folders, you mount volumes, and I don't think APFS supports hard-linking directories. So.... I don't think you can do what you want to do.

Comment: APFS indeed not support hard linking, can I link the same device 2 times? 1-time APFS (the normal default) and 1-time HFS+ ?

Comment: You can't do that; you can only mount the volume in the format it's actually in on disk. What is your actual goal, and why wouldn't a symbolic link work?

Comment: I have old software that demands HardLinking that works only on HFS+, can't I mount the hard disk device 2 times? one the normal and one to HFS+?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197029/how-do-you-mount-bind-a-local-directory